# How to clear the search text in the edit text on back press in android

Tags: android, listview

i have a edit text and when i search the results are fine. but if i back press and come back the result remain the same, rather how to clear the edit text and load the fresh list.. help me please thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the activity is being reloaded by checking the Bundle in onCreate():

In the Activity containing the EditText you want to blank when you go back to it you need this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    EditText searchBox = ...
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        searchBox.setText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
           searchBox.setText("");
}
```

try this one